# Golang app behind Nginx reverse proxy won't accept ajax request on firefox due to CORS

Tags: ajax, nginx, go, proxy, cors

So I have a domain name which is a static html file that sends an ajax request to a subdomain app which is behind Nginx in a reverse proxy.

Here is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function call() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://test.example.com/call",
      crossDomain: true,
      data: $("#form-call").serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        $("#response").html(response);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("error");
      }

});
```

And on Nginx I have:

```
    upstream example {
         server 192.168.1.10:6000;
    }
    server {

        listen 443;
        server_name test.example.com;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/afs.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/afs.key;
        proxy_set_header Host             $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Authorization    "";

        client_max_body_size 0;

        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";


        location / {
            proxy_pass https://exapmle;
            proxy_read_timeout 900;
        }
    }
```

And I have this on my golang app to help with CORS:

```
func (s *MyServer) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if origin := req.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
    }
    // Stop here if its Preflighted OPTIONS request
    if req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }
    // Lets Gorilla work
    s.r.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
```

It works fine on chrome, but on firefox I get the error:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://test.example.com/call. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Comment: What exactly is the query? The error message seems to be quite clear on what needs to be done.

Comment: Well, I from what I read, I have enabled CORS in the golang app. I have also forwarded the headers through the proxy, so it shouldn't still give this error, yet it is.

Comment: Is ServeHTTP actually getting the request form Firefox? This is most likely a https certificate problem.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I have just seen how old this post is, I imagine the problem has already been solved.

This worked for me:

```
func corsHandler(fn http.HandleFunc) http.HandleFunc {
    return func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        fn(rw, req)
    }
}
```

Then when setting up your routers you can:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/<route>", corsHandler(handleRouteMethod)).Methods("<METHOD>")
```

Slightly different approach but it has definitely worked, so if all else fails, you could give it a try (this assumes you are using gorilla mux, if you are using the httprouter or something else then your corsHandler method maybe needs to use a different function signature).